# Hide tags in category blog layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags, layout, category-blog

I have some category blog menu items with a couple of articles showing in a blog layout.

The articles are tagged and those are showing above each article preview as well as in the articles themselves.

I would like to hide the tags in the blog layout but still have them visible in the article.

In the options, for the category blog menu item I have tried the following:

1. **Options->Show Tags=Hide** -  but that seems to hide them both in the blog layout and in the articles.
2. **Category->Show Tags=Hide** - hide the category tags which I'm not using.

Is there a setting somewhere for this? Or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short this is the hierarchy.

Menu item layout can be overridden by Article options and the the Article Page itself has the final say so if you will.

Comment: Thank you, that works. The global setting for articles are to show tags but that seems to be overridden by the menu layout, but setting "Show Tags" individually for each article gives the result I want.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it did indeed work out. @Edvin ... Suriah?